# Calculate the sum in the rows of the array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a two-dimensional array A. I need
the elements of the array are written to the elements of the dynamic array elements record the calculated sum of the row of the  array A. The dynamic array elements are displayed using pointers.

```
const unsigned row = 3;
const unsigned col = 4;
int A[row][col];
std::cout << "Input A:\n";
for (int index = 0; index < row; ++index) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j) 
    {
        std::cout << "A[" << index << "][" << j << "]=";
        std::cin >> A[index][j];
    }
}
unsigned* array = new unsigned[row];
for (int index = 0; index < row; ++index)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j)
    {
        array[index] += A[index][j];
    }
}


for (unsigned* index = array; *index; ++index) 
{
    std::cout << *index << "\n";
}
```

But alas, it does not work properly. Help me figure it out.

UPD:

```
unsigned* end = array + row + 1;
std::cout << "Array:\n";
for (unsigned *ptr = array, index = 1; ptr <= end; ++ptr, ++index)
{
    std::cout << *ptr << "\t";
}
```

Comment: `Does not work properly` What are we trying to achieve here ?

Comment: elements of `A` are not initialized. This will print some random integers.

Comment: @Wander3r ...or nasal demons

Comment: @Pratham 
The wrong amount is recorded. I need to get into a dynamic array under the index
 0 is the sum of 23, for example, and when I display it does not show 23 but 4567 is displayed.

Comment: @Wander3r 
I don't show all the code. I have an array A initialized

Comment: @oksanavovl In that case, can you show the required code for us to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @Wander3r UPD all my code

Comment: Think critically. What is the value of `array[index]` before you attempt `array[index] += A[index][j];`? (hint: indeterminate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never initialized the `array` so this line has [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub):

```
array[index] += A[index][j];
```

You can simply fix if with:

```
for (int index = 0; index < row; ++index) { 
    array[index] = 0;
}
```

Or:

```
for (int index = 0; index < row; ++index) {
   unsigned sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j) { 
      sum += A[index][j]; 
      }
   array[index] = sum;
}
```

And the last output can be changed too. Your version reads out of bounds so yet another undefined behavior.

```
for (int index = 0; index < row; ++index) { 
   std::cout << array[index] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Oblivion reinstateOurMonica 
I have an array  A of initializations. I just did not put all the code

Comment: @oksanavovl how about the array? Did you initialized it too?

Comment: You will not understand. I need to initialize the array by the dynamic sum of the rows of array A

Comment: @oksanavovl you cannot. Please refer to the link. You have to do what I wrote first, then do sum you have in your code. Or store the result of sum in a temporary and then initialize the array with that

Comment: @oksanavovl please see the edit I added another code snippet

Comment: thank you. You still have such a question. At the end, I output the array through the headlight, but instead of 3 lines, it outputs 6. That is, 3 correct and 3 somehow unclear. Am I outputting the array correctly?

Comment: @ Oblivion reinstateOurMonica no. It is impossible. I did so and the teacher said to do through pointers.

Dynamic array elements with pointers are displayed.

Comment: @oksanavovl ok so you need another pointer that points to the one passed the last unsigned* end = array + row +1; and the condition will be index != end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201984/discussion-between-oksana-vovl-and-oblivion-reinstateourmonica).